# how to change a form background color using jquery while using input[type=text];

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I know my title my be a little confusing, maybe someone can suggest a different one.

So anyways, i am learning some Jquery, i want to us it for form validation, I'll show the code then asked the question.

Form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="market_1">Market: </label>
            <input type="text" name="market_1" id="market_1" />
        </li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#market_1").addClass("text_box_error");
});
```

CSS:

```
input[type="text"]
{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #5B5B5B;
    width: 148px;
}

input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="text"]:focus 
{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border: 1px solid #5B5B5B;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.text_box_error 
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

At the moment, i've just trying to get it to change colour when i click the submit button. Now i can get this to work, but i can't get it to work when i using `input[type="text"]` to style the input boxes.

I thought by doing that i can style all the input boxes the same and then using the jquery addClass method i can override the background colour.

So why doesn't this work with the set up i have shown you?

EDIT:
Sorry i have updated the code and pasted the wrong version here, i have no updated the code.

Comment: What does $(".input_boxes") give?

Comment: Sorry @hop It was a mistake on my part, i have updated the question.

Comment: The reason for .input_boxes was to give it the properties of input[type=text] and see if that worked and it did but i don't understand the difference.

Comment: Just saying, `input[type="text"]` is not cross browser, adding a class and applying rules on it is more appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with [selector specifity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

The selector `input[type="text"]` contains an element name and refers to an attribute, so it has a specifity of `0,0,1,1`.

The selector `.text_box_error` however contains only one (class) attribute, so it has a specifity of `0,0,1,0` – and therefor its `background-color` gets overwritten by the other selector which has a higher specifity.

Just use `input[type="text"].text_box_error` as a selector – that’ll have a specifity of `0,0,2,1` and will therefor “win” over the first selector.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot buddy, i had no idea one way of doing things could have a higher priority than another. I always assumed that the last thing to be executed would be the code that overwrite.... Guess that is a bit primitive. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This selector is looking for elements with a class of `input_boxes`, yet you have no elements with this class name in your HTML.

```
$(".input_boxes")
```

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake on my part, i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to:

```
input[type="text"].text_box_error
{
    background-color: red;
}

input[type="text"].text_box_error:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

And you can correctly style both the cases when the text box has an error and when it doesn't.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5KjVC/